# Absolute convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx^n$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, power-series, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

I have to find an $a_n$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n $ converges absolutely on $[-1,1]$. I have choosen $a_n = \frac {1}{n^2}$ and did the root test and see that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (|a_n|) =1$. Now I know that if the result of the root test was < 1 then it would converge $\forall |x| < 1 $. How can i show it it holds even on -1 and 1?

Comment: I'm lazy and would have taken $a_n=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|a_nx^{n}| \leq \frac  1 {n^{2}}$ so you can apply Comparison Test.

Comment: But how does that tell me that my power serie does converge absolutely on $x=-1$ and $x=1$?

Comment: If $|a_n| \leq b_n$ and $\sum b_n <\infty$ then $\sum  a_n$ is absolutely convergent. This is called the Comparison Test.  @MariaFernandez

Comment: thank you. I did not know that the comparison test is also a test for absolute convergence @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: The comparison test allows you to check convergence of nonnegative series.  When applied to the **absolute** value of a series, it proves **absolute** convergence. @Maria